# Reference to function return by value and auto

Tags: c++, reference, constants, auto

From why I understood, when you define a variable as a reference to a function return by value you actually have a reference to a temporary object with a lifetime that is bound to the reference and you must have that reference declared as `const`.

That being said, why isn't the temporary defined as a `const` such that `a2` in the example below would be automatically `const`?
If you aren't allowed to bind a non-const reference to that temporary object, then why not make the temporary object itself `const` by default? What's the reason to keep it non-const?

```
#include <string>

std::string getStringA()
{
    std::string myString = "SomeString";
    return myString;
}

const std::string getStringB()
{
    std::string myString = "SomeString";
    return myString;
}


int main()
{
    const std::string temp;

    std::string &a1 = getStringA();        // std::string& a1, warning C4239 : nonstandard extension used : 'initializing' : conversion from 'std::string' to 'std::string &'
    auto &a2 = getStringA();               // std::string& a2, warning C4239 : nonstandard extension used : 'initializing' : conversion from 'std::string' to 'std::string &'
    const std::string &a3 = getStringA();  // all good

    auto &b1 = getStringB();               // const std::string& b1
    auto &b2 = temp;                       // const std::string& b2
}
```

Comment: Your example with `getStringA` only work due to a non-standard visual c++ extension.

Comment: So in order to have a reference to a function like `getStringA()`, you must always have to return a `const`? e.g. `getStringB()`.

Comment: I suggest never to return a `const` value. See my answer.

Comment: If you were adding `const` automatically in this case, this would make the code harder to read and debug... If you want a `const` ref with `auto`, use `const auto &a2`, this is meaningful.

Comment: you can also bind an rvalue reference to a return by value, much easier to type auto&&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to return a `const` value, because it will [kill move semantics](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/685ce46419d7320e).

```
struct A {
    A() = default;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A(A const&) = delete;
};

A       foo() { return {}; }
A const bar() { return {}; }

int main()
{
  A a1 {foo()};
  A a2 {bar()}; // error here
}
```

And that is too much of a price to pay, just to spare yourself the hassle of typing `auto const&` for binding to a temporary.